# Updating autoconf on CentOS

Tags: autoconf

I am working on a CentOS 6.8 system without root privileges. It has autoconf 2.63 installed. I need a more recent version to install something. I downloaded autoconf 2.69 and installed from source (using `/configure --prefix=$home`, because I have no root privileges).

It seemed to work. But when I try `autoconf --version` it still gives me the old version 2.63.

I tried setting the `$PATH` to the folder of the new installation, and even tried going into that folder and running `autoconf --version` there, but I keep getting the old version.

Any thoughts?